# Call to a member function rawFirms() on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have a model called Raw that has many RawFirms

```
class Raw extends Model
{

    public function rawFirms(){
        return $this->hasMany(RawFirm::class);
    }
}
```

and in my Seeder I have this code part:

```
try{
    $raw = $raw_children->raws()->create([
        'name'=>$leaf,
        'quantity'=>0
     ]);
    // if(!$raw){
    //     throw new \Exception;
    // }
}
catch(Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
    $error_code = $e->errorInfo[1];
    if($error_code == 1062){
        $raw = Raw::where('name', $l)->first();
    }
}

$position_id = $faker->numberBetween(1, 432);
//creating rawFirm for three types
if($firm_id != ''){
    foreach(range(0, 2) as $type){
        $raw->rawFirms()
        ->create([
            'firm_id'=>$firm_id,
            'position_id'=>$position_id,
            'quantity'=>0,
            'type'=>$type,
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I want to create `rawFirm` by `$raw->rawFirms()`, it shows an error

> Call to a member function rawFirms() on null.

**However, I debugged raw object and it returned not-null object.** Can anyone help me find the problem.

Comment: *However, I debugged raw object and it returned not-null object.* Okay, so what *is* `$raw`? A not-null object is very vague.

Comment: $raw is the object of Raw class. When I debugged it returned a collection. I mean it was not null as error says

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code:

```
catch(Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
```

should be replaced by:

```
catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
```

(notice leading backslash) or maybe more general

```
catch(\Exception $e){
```

if you want to catch any type of exception.

In addition you used:

```
$error_code = $e->errorInfo[1];
if($error_code == 1062){
    $raw = Raw::where('name', $l)->first();
}
```

but what in case $error_code is different? Then you don't set `$raw` to anything.

Additionally in case you catch this exception you should probably log it like this:

```
catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
    \Log::error($e);
    $error_code = $e->errorInfo[1];
    if($error_code == 1062){
        $raw = Raw::where('name', $l)->first();
    }
}
```

Now you really don't know why this exception happened if you don't log it.